# can we escape qoutes after defiend variables in php

Tags: php

why is not possible to escape quotes from input in php etc:

```
$x = "$_GET[1]";

> www.site.com/a.php?1=";phpinfo();"
```

after doing this the code should be like this :

```
$x = "";phpinfo();"";
```

but instead it looks like this :

```
$x = " ";phpinfo();" ";
```

why phpinfo() not executed after doing this ? im not asking about how we can execute phpinfo , im asking why is not executed after doing this escape ?

Comment: As it's a string, the string may contain quotes and php code as well.  The main thing is you are still dealing with a string, you are not asking it to execute the string contents, just display it.

Comment: @NigelRen can you explain more ?